# Import data into DataFrame with additional commas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data file as such:

```
ID,ORIG,TIME,TEXT
364,1,7-10-15,This works fine
16254,1,7-10-15,But, I don't work :(
9846,0,7-10-15,Neither, do, I
```

When I import using pandas I'm trying to get the following:

```
+-------+------+---------+----------------------+
| ID    | ORIG | TIME    | TEXT                 |
+=======+======+=========+======================+
| 3464  | 1    | 7-10-15 | This works fine      |
+-------+------+---------+----------------------+
| 16254 | 1    | 7-10-15 | But, I don't work :( |
+-------+------+---------+----------------------+
| 9846  | 0    | 7-10-15 | Neither, do, I       |
+-------+------+---------+----------------------+
```

Using my script `data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', low_memory=False)`, when I import the 1st row everything is fine (with no index set).

However with the second row since there's a comma there, the data that was originally in ID moves to the index column and everything gets shifted 1 to the left.

```
+-------+----+---------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       | ID | ORIG    | TIME            | TEXT            |
+=======+====+=========+=================+=================+
| 3464  | 1  | 7-10-15 | This works fine | NaN             |
+-------+----+---------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 16254 | 1  | 7-10-15 | But             | I don't work :( |
+-------+----+---------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

The pattern repeats with the more commas are found in the last column. A possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164249/parsing-csv-file-in-pandas-with-commas-in-last-column) to this is to rewrite the file but I'm trying to find a way to simply import it without having to rewrite each file (I have about 65+).

**My question is:**

Is it possible to import (per row) first column into "ID" second column to "ORIG" third column to "TIME" and everything else into "TEXT"?

Comment: Does your data actually have all those `+` and `-` and `=`?

Comment: No, it's just for viewing purpose

Comment: Can you add what the actual input looks like

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you're referring to my data.csv file?

Comment: It's usually a better idea to give an actual example people can copy and paste.  The data file you've shown *wouldn't* have a problem, because it uses `|` as the separator.

Comment: @Leb, yes including how it is delimited

Comment: I updated it, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So `9846,0,7-10-15,Neither, do, I` actually has text where do and I are and the is a space after the comma before do?

Comment: Yes that's exactly how it is

Comment: Then you get a parser error?

Comment: No parsing error, it's shifting everything to the left so instead of "Neither, do, I" being under "TEXT" column, because of the extra commas, "I" is under the "TEXT", "do" gets shifted to "TIME" and "Neither" to "ORIG". In this specific one, "7-10-15" goes under "ID" and the remain become indexes.

Comment: There is no way you don't get an error with what you have in your question, add a few lines exactly as they are in your file.

Comment: @Leb: python 2 or 3?

Comment: @DSM it's python 3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSV is malformed because it does not use quotes to distinguish commas which are delimiters from commas which are part of a field's value.

However, we could iterate through the lines of the CSV and use [`str.split(',', 3)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split *on just the first 3 commas*:

```
lines = (line.split(',',3) for line in f)
```

We can pass this iterator directly to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=header)
```

This will not be as fast loading valid CSV using `pd.read_csv`'s optimized parsing engine, but I think the result pretty good considering the input is malformed.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

with open('data', 'r') as f:
    header = [item.strip() for item in next(f).split(',')]
    lines = (line.split(',', 3) for line in f)
    df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=header)
    df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
    df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])

print(df)
```

yields

```
      ID  ORIG       TIME                    TEXT
0    364     1 2015-07-10       This works fine\n
1  16254     1 2015-07-10  But, I don't work :(\n
2   9846     0 2015-07-10        Neither, do, I
```

with

```
print(df.dtypes)
# ID               int64
# ORIG             int64
# TIME    datetime64[ns]
# TEXT            object
# dtype: object
```

Comment: All answers worked, but since yours resulted in the faster output on my larger files I marked as the accepted answer

Comment: Actually, this answer *is* better (at least than mine) because it stops splitting after 3 commas.

Answer (score 2):

It's a tad ugly, but you could use [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) using on-the-fly data:

```
crap = [l.split(',')[: 3] + [''.join(l.strip().split(',')[3: ])] \
     for l in open('stuff.csv').readlines()]
>> pd.DataFrame.from_records(crap[1: ], columns=crap[0])
      ID ORIG     TIME                 TEXT
0    364    1  7-10-15      This works fine
1  16254    1  7-10-15  But I don't work :(
2   9846    0  7-10-15         Neither do I
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are a few ways to force this to work entirely pandas-side, it's so much easier to do it using `csv` that I'd just do that:

```
import csv, io, pandas as pd
data = io.StringIO()
with open("leb.csv", newline="") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    rows = [row[:3] + [','.join(row[3:])] for row in reader]
    writer = csv.writer(data)
    writer.writerows(rows)

data.seek(0)
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

This effectively fixes up the input data before pandas ever sees it.  This gives

```
>>> df
      ID  ORIG     TIME                  TEXT
0    364     1  7-10-15       This works fine
1  16254     1  7-10-15  But, I don't work :(
2   9846     0  7-10-15        Neither, do, I
```