# Parsing CSV file in pandas with commas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to create a `pandas.DataFrame` from a `csv` file.  For that I am using the method `pandas.csv_reader(...)`. The problem with this file is that one or more columns contain commas within the values (I don't control the file format). 
I been trying to implement the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164249/parsing-csv-file-in-pandas-with-commas-in-last-column?answertab=active#tab-top) but I get the following error:

```
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

For some reason after implementing this solution the csv file I tried fixing is blank.

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
# fix csv file
with open ("/Users/username/works/test.csv",'rb') as f,\
open("/Users/username/works/test.csv",'wb') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter=',')
    for line in f:
        row = line.split(',', 4)
        writer.writerow(row)
# Manipulate csv file
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser\
("/Users/username/works/test.csv"),error_bad_lines=False)
```

Any ideas?

**Data overview:**

```
 Id0    Id 1    Id 2 Country Company Title       Email                  
  23    123     456   AR     name    cargador   email@email.com                 

  24    123     456   AR     name    Executive assistant    email@email.com                 

  25    123     456   AR     name   Asistente Administrativo    email@email.com                 

  26    123     456   AR     name   Atención al cliente vía telefónica   vía online email@email.com             
  39    123     456   AR     name   Asesor de ventas    email@email.com                 

  40    123     456   AR     name    inc.   International company representative    email@email.com             
  41    123     456   AR     name   Vendedor de campo   email@email.com                 

  42    123     456   AR     name   PUBLICIDAD   ATENCIÓN AL CLIENTE    email@email.com             
  43    123     456   AR     name   Asistente de Marketing  email@email.com                 

  44    123     456   AR     name   SOLDADOR    email@email.com                 
  217   123     456   AR     name   Se requiere vendedores       Loja    Quevedo     Guayas)    email@email.com 
  218   123     456   AR     name   Ing. Civil recién graduado   Yaruquí    email@email.com             
 219    123     456   AR     name   ayudantes enfermeria    email@email.com                 

 220    123     456   AR     name   Trip Leader for International Youth Exchange    email@email.com                 
 221    123     456   AR     name   COUNTRY MANAGER / DIRECTOR COMERCIAL    email@email.com                 
 250    123     456   AR     name   Ayudante de Pasteleria  email@email.com  Asesor email@email.com email@email.com
```

**Pre-parsed CSV:**

```
#,Id 1,Id 2,Country,Company,Title,Email,,,,
23,123,456,AR,name,cargador,email@email.com,,,,
24,123,456,AR,name,Executive assistant,email@email.com,,,,
25,123,456,AR,name,Asistente Administrativo,email@email.com,,,,
26,123,456,AR,name,Atención al cliente vía telefónica , vía online,email@email.com,,,
39,123,456,AR,name,Asesor de ventas,email@email.com,,,,
40,123,456,AR,name, inc.,International company representative,email@email.com,,,
41,123,456,AR,name,Vendedor de campo,email@email.com,,,,
42,123,456,AR,name,PUBLICIDAD, ATENCIÓN AL CLIENTE,email@email.com,,,
43,123,456,AR,name,Asistente de Marketing,email@email.com,,,,
44,123,456,AR,name,SOLDADOR,email@email.com,,,,
217,123,456,AR,name,Se requiere vendedores,, Loja , Quevedo, Guayas),email@email.com
218,123,456,AR,name,Ing. Civil recién graduado, Yaruquí,email@email.com,,,
219,123,456,AR,name,ayudantes enfermeria,email@email.com,,,,
220,123,456,AR,name,Trip Leader for International Youth Exchange,email@email.com,,,,
221,123,456,AR,name,COUNTRY MANAGER / DIRECTOR COMERCIAL,email@email.com,,,,
250,123,456,AR,name,Ayudante de Pasteleria,email@email.com, Asesor,email@email.com,email@email.com,
251,123,456,AR,name,Ejecutiva de Ventas,email@email.com,,,,
```

Comment: Can you add an overview of your file's data ?

Comment: I have added the overview of the data. Thanks

Comment: I think @ChihebNexus was asking for the pre-parsed CSV data so we can see how to properly parse it.

Comment: got it, added as   pre-parsed CSV

Comment: I see.  If that's the case, it looks like someone is giving you bad data to work with.  Is that the point?  you're being asked to clean it up?  The reason I ask is because row #217 has the email at the end of the line, instead of four columns from the right.  Can you get the data any closer to the source?  Typically a string that has potential for commas would be surrounded by quotes: `"bla,bla,bla"`

Comment: I need to open this CSV with 7 columns.  The problem is that since there are commas in some strings the CSV ends up with more than 7 columns.  The solution I got from stackoverflow produced a blank csv instead of fixing it. 
Is there a way to edit the CSV to add quotes using python? So when I run the script it will first fix the CSV and then proceed to open it with pandas.
And no, it would be great if I could but I can't control how I get the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can assume that for the Comapny, that any commas are followed by spaces, and that all of the remaining errant commas are in the column prior to the email address, then a small parser can be written to process that.

**Code:**

```
import csv
import re

VALID_EMAIL = re.compile(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+')

def read_my_csv(file_handle):
    # build csv reader
    reader = csv.reader(file_handle)

    # get the header, and find the e-mail and title columns
    header = next(reader)
    email_column = header.index('Email')
    title_column = header.index('Title')

    # yield the header up to the e-mail column
    yield header[:email_column+1]

    # for each row, go through rebuild columns
    for row in reader:

        # for each row, put the Company column back together
        while row[title_column].startswith(' '):
            row[title_column-1] += ',' + row[title_column]
            del row[title_column]

        # for each row, put the Title column back together
        while not VALID_EMAIL.match(row[email_column]):
            row[email_column-1] += ',' + row[email_column]
            del row[email_column]
        yield row[:email_column+1]
```

**Test Code:**

```
with open ("test.csv", 'rU') as f:
    generator = read_my_csv(f)
    columns = next(generator)
    df = pd.DataFrame(generator, columns=columns)

print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
      # Id 1 Id 2 Country     Company  \
0    23  123  456      AR        name   
1    24  123  456      AR        name   
2    25  123  456      AR        name   
3    26  123  456      AR        name   
4    39  123  456      AR        name   
5    40  123  456      AR  name, inc.   
6    41  123  456      AR        name   
7    42  123  456      AR        name   
8    43  123  456      AR        name   
9    44  123  456      AR        name   
10  217  123  456      AR        name   
11  218  123  456      AR        name   
12  219  123  456      AR        name   
13  220  123  456      AR        name   
14  221  123  456      AR        name   
15  250  123  456      AR        name   
16  251  123  456      AR        name   

                                               Title            Email  
0                                           cargador  email@email.com  
1                                Executive assistant  email@email.com  
2                           Asistente Administrativo  email@email.com  
3    Atención al cliente vía telefónica , vía online  email@email.com  
4                                   Asesor de ventas  email@email.com  
5               International company representative  email@email.com  
6                                  Vendedor de campo  email@email.com  
7                    PUBLICIDAD, ATENCIÓN AL CLIENTE  email@email.com  
8                             Asistente de Marketing  email@email.com  
9                                           SOLDADOR  email@email.com  
10  Se requiere vendedores,, Loja , Quevedo, Guayas)  email@email.com  
11               Ing. Civil recién graduado, Yaruquí  email@email.com  
12                              ayudantes enfermeria  email@email.com  
13      Trip Leader for International Youth Exchange  email@email.com  
14              COUNTRY MANAGER / DIRECTOR COMERCIAL  email@email.com  
15                            Ayudante de Pasteleria  email@email.com  
16                               Ejecutiva de Ventas  email@email.com
```

Comment: thanks this works! is there any change that the script can catch cases where the company column is also getting mixed with the title.
An example of this is index 5. It should be the following:
company: name inc.
title: International company representative

Thanks!

Comment: @David, Since the `,` is the field delimiter, you would need to come up with some logic to allow the code to distinguish between company and title. I just added a bit to fix the company by assuming leading spaces go with the previous column. The heuristic I proposed above is obviously simplistic.  This is to psheps point in the comments above.  Data Cleaning is almost always a bit of art, as the way to do it will heavily depend on what is wrong with the data.